# Null JSON response for login in Android

Tags: android, json

I am working with registration and login from server in android. The registration is completed successfully but login gives null response.

My login page is as follows,

```
package com.example.arunraj.locationtracker;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String L_URL= "http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/login";
    EditText e_user,e_pwd;
    String c_username,c_password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        e_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_user);
        e_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_pwd);
        Button b_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_login);
        Button b_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_register);
        b_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                c_username=e_user.getText().toString();
                c_password=e_pwd.getText().toString();
                LoginAsyn loginAsyn=new LoginAsyn();
                loginAsyn.execute(L_URL);
//
            }
        });
        b_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it i present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    class LoginAsyn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;






        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

            //progress dialog
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Login....");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                // 1. create HttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                String json = "";
                // 3. build jsonObject
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("name", c_username);
                jsonObject.put("password", c_password);


                // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                json = jsonObject.toString();

                // 5. set json to StringEntity
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
                // 6. set httpPost Entity
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);







                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;

                inputStream.close();



            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            // 11. return result
            return result;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (nDialog.isShowing()) {
                nDialog.dismiss();
            }



            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }



}
```

The expected json input is as follows,

```
{
   "name":"hima",
   "password":"sample123"
}
```

and response as,

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "hima"
}
```

But I got blank response with org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException. I need help to find the problem.
log cat given below

07-30 12:41:49.713  31015-31015/? V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
07-30 12:41:49.719  31015-31033/? I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
07-30 12:41:49.719  31015-31033/? V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
07-30 12:41:49.878      744-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 31097:com.android.chrome:privileged_process1/u0a34 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.PrivilegedProcessService1
07-30 12:41:49.921  31097-31097/? I/ChildProcessService﹕ Creating new ChildProcessService pid=31097
07-30 12:41:49.924     744-2781/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 27220:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a65 (adj 15): empty #17
07-30 12:41:50.053     744-1192/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 30231:com.google.android.apps.gcs/u0a84 (adj 15): empty #17
07-30 12:41:50.982      744-764/? V/WindowManager﹕ not Base app: Adding window Window{161d5b01 u0 Login....} at 6 of 21
07-30 12:41:51.853  30701-31115/com.example.arunraj.locationtracker I/System.out﹕ exceptionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnorg.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
07-30 12:41:51.881      744-897/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@8173b94 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3dcb4c75

Comment: pleaae suggest solutions

Comment: put some logs on the exception and also log the httpResponse, that should give you some indications on what's going on.

Comment: Plz tell me you put internet permission on manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Please kindly print the logs.. you are probably doing something wrong in your doInBackground Method

Comment: question updated with logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL ="http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/login" is not working. Firstly check it.

Comment: It does work, check @RamIndani answer!  It's a POST request

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there is an exception in your `doInBackground` code that you are swallowing. Try printing out the exception in your catch statement and go from there.

Comment: yes, you are right .i got an exception as apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException. whats the reason for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute your rest api but it gives error 404 saying user not found, I have attached image of REST Client.

[image]

Comment: You don't have user with this username or your REST api is returning false results. You should check for Http Status code before processing response in your android client.

Comment: name ="arya" password="arya123" exist but the response is blank

Answer (score 0):

First things first,  as you may know [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) is deprecated, please use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
class LoginAsyn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        //progress dialog
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Login....");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            // 0. set Proxy Settings (OPTIONAL) <-- am behind a proxy so i need to do this
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.123.123.123", 8080));
            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray()));
                }
            };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

            // 1.  create Http Connection
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            //HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); <-- use this when there's no proxy instead of :
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

            // 2. make POST request
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // 3. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 4. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("name", "hima");
            jsonObject.put("password", "sample123");

            // 5. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            String json = jsonObject.toString();

            // 6. open connection and set the POST body
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            // 7. Get response code
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("StackOverFlow", "POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

            // 8. Handle response
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;
                bufferedReader.close();

                Log.d("StackOverFlow", result);
            }
            else {
                String error = "";
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    error += line;
                bufferedReader.close();

                Log.e("StackOverFlow", "Http Error : "+ responseCode +" message : " + error);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("StackOverFlow", "Other Error", e);
        }

        // 9. return result
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (nDialog.isShowing()) {
            nDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

As @RamIndani said, using the provided json we get an Http error 404 :

```
07-30 11:17:33.490   6824-22293/com.example.stackoverflowtestapp I/StackOverFlow﹕ POST Response Code :: 404
07-30 11:17:33.490   6824-22293/com.example.stackoverflowtestapp E/﹕ Http Error : 404 message : {"message":"User doesn't Exists or Password is incorrect","httpResponse":"404"}
```

Using the following json extracted from the comments :

```
{
   "name":"arya",
   "password":"arya123"
}
```

we get an Http code 302, which is usually response for redirects (Http 302 Moved Temporarily) but seems like your api has rewriten this as Http 302 Found, instead of a Http 200 Ok. This may be the reason why [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) gives you the ClientProtocolException.

So to make things work you just need to handle this Http 302 Found as you'll handle the Http 200 Ok. Modify the provided code above as following :

```
// 8. Handle response
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) { //success
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
    bufferedReader.close();

    Log.d("StackOverFlow", result);
}
```

And voila! The magic is done :

```
07-30 11:25:11.350  27868-29041/com.example.stackoverflowtestapp I/StackOverFlow﹕ POST Response Code :: 302
07-30 11:25:11.350  27868-29041/com.example.stackoverflowtestapp D/StackOverFlow﹕ {"userId":15,"userName":"arya"}
```

Hope it helps!

---------- **Edit** ----------

As a side note, if you are going to handle a REST API on Android I suggest to take a look at [Robospice library](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice)  https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice